# Visual Studio 2012/Windows Phone 8 get results from Async Web Service

Tags: vb.net, web-services, visual-studio-2012

So I'm working on a Windows Phone 8 App (completely new to Windows Phone 8 as well) and I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to get the results from Asynchronous Web Service method but right now the code I just tried fails and says "Expression does not produce a value". Here's the code that I just tried:

```
'Get previous date
Dim pdate As DateTime
pdate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)
Dim previousDate As String = pdate.ToString("d")

Dim service As New MobileService.MobileServiceSoapClient
Dim results As New List(Of String)()
results.AddRange(service.GetErrorTableAsync(DeviceIDAsString, previousDate))
```

So the GetErrorTable Web Service returns an XML set of results and with the iOS App I can parse the XML file to create my array of values (if any exist) but I can't seem to find a consistent answer on how to do the same for Windows Phone/VB. Any guides or tutorials will be very helpful since I have some Web Services that return a large array of objects and some that return just a single value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a callback delegate for this function `GetErrortableAsync` and it would be called `GetErrorTableComplete`. So you add a handler to this delegate. Your names might be slightly diff but should be close enough for you to find them on the service object.

```
AddHandler service.GetErrorTableComplete AddressOf GetErrorTableCompleted
service.GetErrorTableAsync(DeviceIDAsString, previousDate)


Private Sub GetErrorTableCompleted(sender As Object, e As MobileService.GetErrorTableCompleteEventArgs)
  'now you can access the e.Results
End Sub
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to find, so far it looks like it would work so I just need to throw some test data in the DB and see if it get's passed correctly. Thanks for the help

Comment: You can check the return types by hovering over the `e.Results` and see if your matching types.

Comment: Well I don't know if this is an issue with the emulator or the webservice but when I try to get the results by using 'Convert.ToString(e.Result)' all I get is the 'GetErrorTableCompleteEventArgs' as the value for the string.

Comment: Are there other properties on that object? What is it supposed to return?

Comment: `Convert.ToString` might return the name of the object since it is generated code, and not the object itself. use the same type as the `e.Results` returns to you.

Comment: It's supposed to return 4 strings (4 different statuses). But right now I just get the name of the object.

Comment: Ok, so an `Array` or `List(Of T)`? Like I said don't call `.ToString` since that calls the canned function and the name of the function and not the data. Try and Array or List.

Comment: It might also be a custom `class` which would still be available from the `Namespace` from the service.

Comment: When I try to create an array from the results I get an error stating that 'MobileService.ArrayOfXElement' cannot be converted to 'System.Array'. I'm going to read up some more of this ArrayOfXElement that is being returned from the WebService

Comment: Search thru the service object it should a similar object name and that would be the composite class for the result set. By it's name it sounds like an array of [XElements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) - are you familiar with them?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34248/discussion-between-sal-and-dona)